# Stock order execution - limit orders

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-markets

Can someone explain the outcome to the follow scenario:

Buyer A places a limit order to buy 100 shares at $8.00, Seller B places a sale limit order at 7.50 for 40 shares.  What price would Seller B receive for his shares?

I suspect $8.00, is that correct?  B was the last to place the order so I presume $8.00.  Whereas if the placement of the orders was reversed and B placed sale order at $7.50 and A placed a buy order at $8.00 that A would received 40 shares at $7.50.

Clarification anyone?

Comment: Yes this is correct.

Related question http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15156/how-do-exchanges-match-limit-orders