# Is it possible to sell a stock at a higher value than the market price?

Tags: india, stock-markets

I want to sell a stock of the company XYZ. Its market price is 300rs. I want to sell the stock for 305rs. Is that possible? How might I do that?

Comment: You can sell your shares at any price you want. The kicker is will anyone  buy it at that price?

Comment: Yes, I suspect if you looked at options there may be ways to sell at a higher price though it may cost you to acquire the opportunity I suspect.

Comment: Read this question. It should help you with basics. If you still need clarifications, ask another question. https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15156/how-do-exchanges-match-limit-orders

Comment: If you can, anyone can - and anyone can then make 5 Rs profit by buying stock at 300 and selling at 305. This in a nutshell is called the _effective market hypothesis_ . There's no free money to be found, certainly not instantly and without risk.

Comment: Really, the sale itself makes the price "market price," so no, by definition you sell at market price.

Answer (score 9):

You can ask for 305rs, but as long as shares are available at lower prices you won't sell. Only when your ask becomes the lowest available price will someone buy from you.

See many past questions about how buyers and sellers are matched by the market.

Comment: If the stock is held in a brokerage account, you simply place a sell order with a limit price of 305rs. The trade will not actually happen until there are no shares available for a lower price, of course.

Comment: @keshlam : Your answer may be right..because i have studied in internet saying ask price should be the lowest available price to all..so can I come to the conclusion that ask price should be lowest which is available in market and someone should also be ready to buy it if price is more than trading price..??

Comment: @Anitha To a first approximation, you can buy and sell stock at the advertise bid and ask prices and you can place orders that will fill when the market moves to the price you select. If you want to get more complicated than that, it varies by specific markets and contexts. Usually, market makers are specifically employed to ensure that there is always supply and demand with a reasonably narrow spread so that small quantities can be traded on demand.

Answer (score 0):

The core issue is to understand what 'selling a share' means. There is no special person or company that takes the share from you; you are *selling on the open market*.
So your question is effectively *'can I find a guy on the street that buys a 10$-bill for 11$ ?'*  - Well, maybe someone is dumb enough, but chances are slim.

Comment: Actually, most major markets have [market makers](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/marketmaker.asp) who are specifically employed to ensure that there is a special company to take the share from you. Otherwise, you could get a bad price if you happen to try to sell a share of stock at a time when there happens not to be a buyer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

1. You could write a covered call and the stock gets called away at the price + premium.
2. You could convince someone to buy it regardless of the market price.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but some conditions apply.
You can sell shares a higher price than the market price using Company's [**Buyback offer**](https://www.siptolumpsum.net/2019/01/share-bajar-se-kam-jokhim-le-kar-paisa-kaise-kamae.html).  Generally, all the companies set Buyback Price above the Market value of the shares. But if you have shares of those companies at the record date.