# Bought stock at higher price than current price

Tags: stocks, financial-literacy, stock-exchanges, penalty

1. I wanted to buy stock ABCD at a price of 880. The current price was 900. When I bought, I set 980 instead of 880 and it was fully executed. I don't understand how it is possible to buy stock at a higher price than current price?
2. Now let's say I own stock ABCD in my account, then do I get any penalty for having bought it at a higher price?

I am really worried about what to do...!

Comment: At what price did your buy execute?  Did you actually pay $980?

Comment: Asking (2) is the _really_ concerning part, IMO.  Everyone's pointing out what/that you should know about buy orders, but it seems like you don't even know what stocks are.  You should probably figure that out before you go buying them, regardless of the mechanism or price used to buy them.

Comment: Why do mods keep deleting comments on this question?

Comment: @MooseBoys were the comments used for asking clarifications? If not (like this comment itself), then they're rightly deleted. Anyway, comments are 2nd-class citizen and ephemeral on SE, so don't be surprised if they're gone sometime later.

Comment: For the life of me I don't know why anyone has written an answer.  In my mind this bid order hits the orderbook and transacts on the lowest ask.  There has been no clarification of the ACTUAL execution price, only that there was an ORDER entered at well above the last traded price.  I can't imagine that the matching engine would ignore the best asks in favor of a higher price, in the event of a normally liquid security, not some unicorn $900 per share thinly traded stock.

Comment: We (the mods) might delete comments on any post that aren't needed under the [rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - see [here]( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) for some amplification. We tend to focus on posts that have a lot of comments.

This site is not a discussion board - if you want to say something and have it preserved, write an answer, if it is an answer. If it's not an answer, consider carefully whether you need to say it at all to help the question get answered. If you want to discuss this policy, please post on meta.

Answer (score 103):

> I don't understand is it possible to buy stock at higher price than current price?

This is a very common misunderstanding.

**Stocks *do not have* a "current price" that you can buy them for.**

Any "stock price" that you see quoted is *not* like a price in a store that means you can buy at that price. Instead, a "stock price" only tells you at what price the stock *was* traded at some point *in the past*.

When you enter a buy order with a price, you're *offering* to buy at that price. The stock exchange will match your order with many other orders and determine the price at which the most stock can be traded, and then executes the matching orders.

Chances are that if you entered a price of 880 for your order, it would not have been executed since nobody was willing to sell at that price. It is possible that you could have gotten the stock cheaper if there were no other buyers and the sellers had a lower limit.

These kind of big differences generally only happen on small exchanges with illiquid stock that is rarely traded. Which is why that kind of stock is inherently risky, partially because past price information is pretty meaningless.

Comment: This answer is particularly correct.  I would especially draw everyone's attention to the **last paragraph** which is, again, wholly correct.  (There seems to be some considerable confusion on this QA: I for example naturally assumed, from the question, that the OP was trading something "very illiquid on a small exchange".)

Comment: The stock market could either favour sellers (by always selling to the highest bidding buyers) or the buyers (by always buying from the cheapest sellers, and returning the difference). Which of the two is it?

Comment: @Alexander, it's not that simple, but the short answer is, the buyers. The sellers who are filling your buy order are the lowest offers on the market (or else they'd fill someone else's order).

Comment: There's (near-)perfect symmetry between buyers and sellers. When you sell to the market, you trade with the current best bid. The real answer to Alexander's question AIUI is the market (generally) favours whoever arrived later.

Comment: @Alexander: my understanding is that the market favors neither - it chooses (as I wrote) the price at which the greatest trading volume among all current sellers and buyers is possible. Of course it's easy to produce simplified scenarios where this still gives a price range to choose from, but in reality this is the exception rather than the norm.

Comment: @Alexander As Ben said, the market "favors" whoever came later.  To elaborate on this, it means if you enter a limit order to buy at 990 while there are already orders to sell at, for example, 950, then the price you'll pay is 950, not 990.  If there aren't enough sell orders at 950 then, depending on the order type (all or none vs partial fill) your order could become a standing bid so that the next person to enter an order to sell at anything lower than 990 will actually trigger the 990 price at execution.

Answer (score 40):

> I set 980 instead of 880 and it is fully executed.

Suppose I'm on the other side of your transaction. I might own a stock worth around that $900 price, but have a $980 target. In other words, I'm happy to sell it for $980, so I have a standing sell order at $980. If any bids appear at $980, and I'm a willing seller at that price, I might see my order fill. Let it be a lesson, you just need to be very careful when placing orders.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74676/discussion-on-answer-by-joetaxpayer-bought-stock-at-higher-price-than-current-pr). Newly posted comments on this answer will be deleted with prejudice.

Answer (score 27):

The limit order will match to best offer on books. Let's say the best sell price was 900, it will match to that. You will pay 900.

Read [How do exchanges match limit orders?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15156/how-do-exchanges-match-limit-orders/15161#15161)

Comment: That's the real clearest answer. But the OP can only know the actual  price he paid by checking the transaction history of his brokerage account.

Comment: @LordOfThePigs That is true.

Answer (score 14):

> 1. I don't understand how it is possible to buy stock at a higher price than current price?

The price listed on a stock ticker is not an absolute "price." It is simply the price at which the stock has most recently traded at.

A trade will execute when books are able to match Buyer to Seller at an agreed upon price. In your example, you erroneously agreed upon 980 and it was matched to a Seller who agreed upon 980.

Few scenarios to clarify when a order will match/execute:

1. Buyer sets limit order at 880, Seller sets limit order at 880. Matched at 880.
2. Buyer sets limit order 880, Seller sets limit order 920: No match until someone budges on agreed price or a market order enters the mix.
3. Seller sets market order. Matched to first available Buyer.
4. Buyer sets market order: Matched to first available Seller.

[Investopedia: Orders Market/Limit Differences](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/100314/whats-difference-between-market-order-and-limit-order.asp)

> 2. Do I get any penalty for having bought it at a higher price?

There is no formal penalty.

"Price is what you pay, value is what you get." -Warren Buffett-

The clerical error made on your part of typing 980 instead of 880 most likely cost you money. If you had entered the the desired 880 it might have been filled when a limit sell order at 880 or below was entered or a market order. And only if you were the top buying bid (i.e. if a buy limit order existed at 890 it would be matched before yours).

Learning about [Level II](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/trading/06/level2quotes.asp) might make this more clear

Answer (score 6):

> 2. Now let's say i got that stock in my account, then **do i get any penalty for buying it higher price?**

There's no "penalty" involved (at least in how I would interpret that term).

*If* you had entered your intended price correctly (880), and *if* the price then went on to drop from 900 to that value (or below) *then* you would have got the stock at a lower price, and you *potentially* might have saved some money. *If* the price then turned around and rose, your potential profit would have been greater than having bought it at 900. On the other hand, the price could have continued to drop and you would be out of pocket.

However, there is no guarantee that the price *would* have dropped initially: it may have remained at around 900 or, indeed, have risen. In either of those cases, your order at 880 *wouldn't* have been fulfilled and you *wouldn't* own a stock. If the price *were* to rise, you would have been better off entering the "incorrect" value (buying at 900; able to sell for *some* profit) than having entered the "correct" value (never having bought the stock; no possibility of a profit). Of course the price could also have fallen after buying at 900 and you would have a higher loss than *if* you had bought at 880.

In other words: depending entirely on the (unknowable) future price of the stock you could have gained or lost money either way. Under some scenarios it would have been better to enter the "correct" price; under others it would have been better having entered the "wrong" price.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to buy a stock at higher than the quoted price. When you buy a stock, it is important to set a limit order. The price can also change pretty substantially, so if this was a volatile stock, it would've been better to set a "limit", meaning you cannot buy past a certain limit. Since you had to enter a price, i'm assuming you did buy at a limit, which means your broker would get you a price at the best available price. I could set a limit at $1,000 for a stock quoted at $900, but this doesn't mean that my order will fill at $1,000. It means that I will buy up to the price available being at $1,000 (in simplified terms).

Answer (score 2):

No one has yet mentioned how the HFT (high frequency trading) algorithms and/or dark pools would factor into this situation:

If a stock is currently trading at $900/901 lets say (highest bid 900, lowest ask 901) and you offer to buy at $980, a front running algorithm (typically run very close to the exchange with very fast computers) will see your order come in and know that it could immediately sell to you for 980 and then (before any other orders) buy the ask from the order book at $901 for a $79 profit. For this reason is is possible to buy a stock far higher than currently priced, which is why care must always be taken during any financial transaction.

Comment: This is completely untrue.