# My stock's limit sell order should have filled at a higher price

Tags: stocks, trading, limit-order

New investor here, using the Robinhood platform. I quickly learned that placing market orders never really nets you what the app indicates; limit buys and sells fix that. Typically, I assume, limit sell orders fill at the moment a stock's price hits your limit while on an upswing, but I also thought it must be possible to fill a limit sell at a higher price if the market opens higher than that limit. Indeed, I've noticed that when placing a limit order the app tells me my stock will be sold at my limit price or better.

Today I see that my pending limit sell order for PDS at $4.11/share executed at $4.11/share, but the market opened at $4.13 per share, and it was even higher in pre-market.

So my question is, why didn't I get credited at the $4.13 price?

https://www.google.com/search?tbm=fin&q=PDS

[PDS price chart, cursor shows price at market open on May 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f09Od.png)

Comment: How do you think the market opened at a higher price?

Comment: @Joe The Robinhood app provides this information, and it's also in the linked Google finance chart for the specific stock in question.

Comment: Perhaps there were other sell orders placed before yours? They could have filled all the open buy orders above $4.11.

Comment: I didn't mean "how did you know it opened".  I mean, what do you think the mechanism was for it to jump from 4.06 to 4.13?

Comment: @Joe Actually, as you can see in Google's chart the previous close was 4.03...and it didn't really "jump" to 4.13, it simply began trading higher in post-market hours and continued to trade higher during pre-market today. If you're asking why, I can't really say. Why do any stocks go up?

Comment: @CraigW I guess that could be, but the limit sell has been pending for almost a month. And wouldn't my order at least execute at 4.12/share? Plus it was actively traded in pre-market hours, even as high as 4.23/share.

Comment: The share price hasn't been that high in over a year. I suspect there were many other limit sell orders out there, i.e. people thinking if it gets this high, I want to lock in some or all of my gains. There is no reason why your order would execute at $4.12, because previous sell orders could have filled all buy orders above $4.11. By the time it got to your order apparently the highest bid left was $4.11. You can't determine much here from pre-market trading, but by the end of that session it had fallen to $4.09 anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read some articles that suggest that Robinhood receives payment for routing their orders to specific market makers.  I don't know if this is true or not but this can lead to inferior fills.

PDS opened at $4.13 per share and that price is where the first trades occurred.  PDS appears to have traded with a one cent wide  spread all day but what it was at the open is unknown.  If it was $4.11 x $4.13 then since your limit order was to sell at $4.11,  you were  filled  at your limit price.  Even if it was $4.13 x $4.14 ($4.14 was the day's high), other orders may have been filled before your  order reached the head of the queue and it had dropped to a bid of $4.11  by the time you sold.   There's  no mystery as to why you got $4.11 instead of $4.13.

Just over 60,000 shares traded in the pre-market, mostly between $4.15 and $4.25.  The real question is if you placed your order to sell early in the pre-market, why weren't you filled at a higher price? Check your confirm's time and sales to see when you were filled.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I am only allowed to trade during market hours, extra hours trading is available to Robinhood Gold members as I understand. My limit ordered has been queued for almost a month, is it still likely that everyone drained the selling pool before me? I've seen limit sells get executed pretty much instantly as a climbing stock hits my limit...it just seems super odd that a declining stock would trigger differently, and at exactly my limit price no less. I guess I still don't understand.

Comment: What was the time of execution of your order?  Did it occur in the pre-market or after 9:30 AM EST?  After you spell that out, if you want, I'll try to deal with what you don't understand.

Comment: Here are the details.. Limit Price:$4.11 Entered Quantity: 9
Filled:May 18, 2018, 9:30 AM EDT
Filled Quantity: 9 shares at $4.11 Total:$36.99
Settlement Date: May 22, 2018
So when you say Robinhood may route their orders in ways that earn them a profit, could it be that they simply pocketed $0.02 per share of my sale, since the order did still satisfy my limit criteria?

Comment: @randomguy - No, I'm not saying that RH pocketed your 2 cents.  If trading at market prices, you buy at the ask and sell at the bid.  If the stock's price is rising, your order is executed as soon as you are first in the queue at your limit price and there is a buyer at that price for enough shares.    It doesn't matter how high the stock went after your order was filled.  The problem I have with this RH story is that pre-market price was higher but your GTC order was not filled until 9:30 AM.

Comment: Pre-market and after-hours trades are only filled for members of RH Gold, which I am not. There are some important details about how that works on their [extended trading hours](https://support.robinhood.com/hc/en-us/articles/214681903-Extended-Trading-Hours) page. So the only logical conclusion is that enough other traders were ahead of me in the queue to snatch up all the selling offers above $4.11, such that when it came time to process my order the best sell price happened to be my limit price. I am curious then, if my limit was at $4.09, _would I have still_ been filled at 4.11?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something in your description, here's what looks shady to me.   You placed a GTC order almost a month ago to sell PDS at $4.11 and it traded 14 cents above above that during the pre-market on Friday.  So Robinhood didn't execute a marketable order in the pre-market and waited until the opening bell because you don't have approval for extended trading?  I'm not going to go all conspiracy theory here and suggest that they are stealing from you so let's just call it shoddy practice not to fill you during extended because you don't pay for a higher level of service (Gold).

Comment: If share price progresses upward in an orderly fashion then you get filled at your limit price.  So if your limit was at $4.09, you would have still been filled at 4.09 unless the stock had gapped up past your limit price.  That's about all I have to offer about this other than RH is good for the guy with a small account because they don't charge commissions but I surmise that their executions may negate that and the negative articles and comments out on the web may indeed be true.

Comment: RH claims itself to be a zero-commission broker, so in that regard I'm quite happy and can't expect them to go above-and-beyond other brokerages. That said, they are 100% electronic and they certainly could offer extended hours trading to everyone; it just doesn't fit their business model. If I see this happening a lot I may just sign up for Gold, I believe it's only $5 a month. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @BobBaerker I use Fidelity and Vanguard. Fidelity asks you to enroll separately for extended-hours trading. Vanguard doesn't offer it at all. I suspect very few if any brokerages would execute an order in extended-hours trading unless you specifically requested that.

Comment: @randomguy - I think that it does fit their business model.  If you want something more, you have to pay for it :->)

Comment: @Craig W - When a broker accepts an order, it  has the legal duty of "best execution." Despite having traded during after hours for 20+ years, I don't know what the rules are for new accounts today. Therefore, I may be splitting hairs by having the expectation that if  you place a GTC order, with that responsibility,  the broker should execute the order if that price is available during  after hours, regardless of whether you are approved for extended hours trading or not.    Requiring application and approval in order for them to  perform "best execution"  seems like subterfuge to me.

Answer (score 1):

> but I also thought it must be possible to fill a limit sell at a higher price if the market opens higher than that limit. Indeed, I've noticed that when placing a limit order the app tells me my stock will be sold at my limit price or better.

When a limit order is being placed [just when it hits the exchange] for 4.11; it can match to higher buy order for more than 4.11
If the limit order is sitting on exchange [like you mentioned GTC], there is no situation it will match for a higher price. Even if there is a subsequent buy order for higher price, it will get matched to 4.11 or anything below it.

Read more at [How do exchanges match limit orders?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15156/how-do-exchanges-match-limit-orders/15161#15161)

> Today I see that my pending limit sell order for PDS at $4.11/share executed at $4.11/share, but the market opened at $4.13 per share, and it was even higher in pre-market.

The Google charts are slightly cluttered. See the same in Yahoo charts. At 9:30 the price was 4.11 and at 9.31 the price was 4.135. So my guess is your order got executed at 4.11 first and then there were other orders at 4.13 that also got executed and then the price moved down.

At 9:30
[image]

At 9:31
[image]