# How is the actual stock transaction price determined?

Tags: stock-markets, stock-exchanges, online-brokerage, transaction

Let's say that for some stock, the current highest bid price is $5.01 and the current lowest ask price is $5.05. Or in more detail, the following orders are queued (for simplicity, only one share per order):

- Ask $5.07 (A1)
- Ask $5.06 (A2)
- Ask $5.05 (A3)
- Bid $5.01 (B1)
- Bid $5.00 (B2)
- Bid $4.99 (B3)

If I were to place an order now, to sell (ask) with a limit of $5.00, what should happen?

1. Will it be matched with order B2?
2. Will it be matched with order B1? In that case, who will be the recipient of the leftover 1 cent?

How would the situation differ in case I would place an order to sell for $1.00 instead of $5.00?

Comment: Alternative explanation: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/142141/execution-price-when-the-trading-price-jumps-over-the-limit-price-for-a-previous/142185#142185

Answer (score 0):

If the highest bid is $5.01 and you place an order to sell at $5.00 then you will receive $5.01 .  If your sell order has a larger voume than the shares that are available at $5.01 then you will also sell some shares at $5.00

If you were to place an order to sell for $1.00 then your limit order would go on the order book.  Perhaps it would be (A-100)?  :->)